# Express js 4, Parse.com JSON error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am trying to send a POST call to an Express JS server hosted on Parse.com. I send the data like this:

```
var data = new Array();     
    data["firstName"] = firstName;
    data["lastName"] = lastName;
    data["dateOfBirth"] = dateOfBirth;
    data["mobileNumbe"] = mobileNumber;
    data["email"] = email;
    data["reEmail"] = reEmail;
    data["pw"] = pw;
    data["rePw"] = rePw;

    $.ajax({
            url: "/api/post/registerclient",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "application/json",
            data: { data:data
                  },
            success: function(result){
                disabledButton("buttonRegister",false);
                if(data.success == true){
                    console.log("Neu registriert");
                }else{
                    showErrorMessageWithError(result.error);
                }
            },
            error:function(error){
                disabledButton("buttonRegister",false);

                var string = "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!"
                showErrorMessageWithError(string);
            }
        });
```

On the server side, I try to catch the data with req.body.data, but it is empty:

```
exports.registerClient = function(req,res){

//Data, get = firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, mobileNumber, email, reEmail, pw, rePw
//Data, respond = success, error
var validation = helper.validateRegisterClient(req.body.data);


if(validation.length == 0){
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", req.data.email);
    user.set("password", req.data.pw);
    user.set("email", req.data.email);

    //optional fields
    user.set("mobileNumber", req.data.mobileNumber);
    user.set("firstName", req.data.firstName);
    user.set("lastName", req.data.lastName);
    user.set("dateOfBirth", req.data.dateOfBirth);

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            var success = true;
            var error = "";

            var json = {success: success, error: error};
            res.json(json);
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            var success = false;

            var json = {success: success, error: error};
            res.json(json);
        }
    });
}else{
    var success = false;
    var error = validation;

    var json = {sucess: success, error: error};
    res.json(json);
}
}
```

I have the feeling, that my express app may be configured wrong, so here is my "init":

```
var express = require('express');
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body
app.use(express.cookieParser('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } }));
```

Comment: Use `var data = {};` instead of `var data = new Array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your express code. You're referencing `req.data` when it should be `req.body.data`:

For instance, this:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", req.data.email);
user.set("password", req.data.pw);
user.set("email", req.data.email);
```

Should be this:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", req.body.data.email);
user.set("password", req.body.data.pw);
user.set("email", req.body.data.email);
```

Also, your initial data array is actually an object and should be instantiated differently.  So this:

```
var data = new Array();
```

Should be this:

```
var data = {};
```

One other thing I noticed just now is that you're referencing `data.success` in your ajax success callback. `data.success` doesn't exist in this scope. This should be `result.success`.

So this:

```
            if(data.success == true){
                console.log("Neu registriert");
            }else{
                showErrorMessageWithError(result.error);
            }
```

Should be:

```
            if(result.success == true){
                console.log("Neu registriert");
            }else{
                showErrorMessageWithError(result.error);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors, but the thing is req.body.data is empty :/

Comment: That's because you're instantiating `var data` with `new Array()`. It should be `var data = {}` instead of `var data = new Array()`. I just tested this myself in Node and the data doesn't translate the way you would expect it to when you use `Array()`. EDIT: Try console.logging `req.body.data` after updating `var data = {}` and report back know what you get.

Comment: I applied all changes, saved the files. Deleted all files from the server, and uploaded them again. Now it´s working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Now after everything works on the server-side, I think I get an Cross Domain error, because the Ajax call always fails, even on success. Should I open a new thread ?

Comment: Yeah, please do. That's a fundamentally different issue